# Oracle Like Operator in Where condition and decode

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write a PL-SQL query to return records from multiple table and using decode to allow null value comparison,

```
PROCEDURE GetResults(FromDate DATE,pToDate DATE, DeptName VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,p_ref  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) IS
BEGIN
OPEN p_ref FOR
SELECT e.First_Name,e.LastName,e.Department
FROM
Employee e, Department d
Where  e.JoiningDate >=FromDate
      AND e.JoiningDate <=ToDate
     AND  NVL(e.Department,'~') = decode(DeptName,null,NVL(e.Department,'~'),DeptName
End GetResults
```

The result is returning only where DeptName is exactly matching to the database values, but I want a query to return  something
`e.Department like '%DeptName%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for anything other than boolean logic:

```
WHERE e.JoiningDate >= FromDate AND
      e.JoiningDate <= ToDate AND
      (DeptName IS NULL OR e.Department = DeptName)
```

If you want a `NULL` parameter to *only* match `NULL` values, then use:

```
WHERE e.JoiningDate >= FromDate AND
      e.JoiningDate <= ToDate AND
      (DeptName IS NULL AND e.Department IS NULL OR 
       e.Department = DeptName
      )
```

I would also recommend that you give your parameters names that are more obviously parameters.  I often prefix with `in_` or `out_`:

```
PROCEDURE GetResults (
    in_FromDate DATE,
    in_ToDate DATE,
    in_DeptName VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    out_p_ref  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
```

Comment: If the in_deptName is not null, I want query all the records where DeptName like '%in_deptName%' and if the parameters is null then I want all the records with DeptName  null values

Comment: @MichaelEdwards . . . Your question makes no mention of `like`, but you can obviously use `like` instead of `=`.